# What does a complete Xamarin IDE setup look like?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm not a new developer but I am new to Xamarin. I'm hoping someone can clue me into how to best use Xamarin from a high-level perspective. I know they offer some great tools but I'm assuming (1) I will still need a Mac (2) I will still need an Apple Developer account.

Are these assumptions correct? Is it possible to use Xamarin and still deploy to iPhone WITHOUT a Mac machine (ie all on a PC)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. You **need** a Mac for iOS development. You can develop and debug from a Windows computer but the build itself needs to be done on a Mac computer (as it requires, among other things, linking with Apple's libraries);
2. You need an Apple developer account to be able to provision and deploy to iOS **devices**. Otherwise you'll be limited to the iOS simulator.

Comment: Thank you. Does the PC version of Xamarin include an iOS simulator?

Comment: No, the iOS simulator is provided as part of Apple Xcode and requires a Mac to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that in order to see what your UI will look like while developing, and in order to have drag/drop development for your UI, you need to be using a MAC, not a PC.  There is no 'Design View' for iOS apps in the Visual Studio pluggin, or in the Windows version of the Xamarin Studio.  The Xamarin Studio on a MAC just navigates you into the XCode IDE and lets you do your drag/drop development in there.

Comment: Unless you are using storyboards, then you can use the new designer in Xamarin Studio.